# Exception thrown from MesageHandler is not returning message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Our application has an implementation of `MessageHandler` which is expected to handle messages from queues. In different environments, we are connected to different queues(GCP PubSub/AMQ).

With GCP PubSub, when an exception is thrown from `MessageHandler#handleMessage` (`org.springfranework.messaging`), the message is returned to PubSub.
Whereas the same thing is not happening with AMQ.

And the `MessageHandler` instance is just returned on method annotated with `ServiceActivator`. i.e., It's not explicitly mapped to anything else.

Simplified configuration that we for AMQ is as below,

**Config creating JMSEndpoint:**

```
private JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(@Autowired MessageChannel inputChannel) {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= new JmsConnectionFactory(username, password, url);

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setDestinationName("my-subscription");
    
    ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
    JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint = new JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(container, listener);
    endpoint.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
    return endpoint;
}
```

**Config for channel:**

```
 @Bean
  public MessageChannel myChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }
```

**ServiceActivator for MessageHandler:**

```
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
  public MessageHandler engagementRegistration() {
    return new CustomHandler();
  }
```

**Simplified Custom handler:**

```
class CustomHandler implements MessageHandler<?>
 {
 public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
 // logic to handle the message and throw MessageException(message)
 // When I have to send back the message
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to see some configuration on the matter...

Probably your GCP PubSub is not configured for auto-ack (or similar name). Or it is auto-ack, but already after the whole process returns control to the GCP consumer.

Not clear what is that AMQ, but probably it acks messages automatically when they reach consumer and it doesn't wait for the process to finish.

**UPDATE**

So, your AMQ is just about JMS.

As I said, you have an auto-ack before an exception.
See `JmsAccessor.sessionAcknowledgeMode`. It is a `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`. And now see its JavaDocs:

```
/** With this acknowledgment mode, the session automatically acknowledges
  * a client's receipt of a message either when the session has successfully 
  * returned from a call to {@code receive} or when the message 
  * listener the session has called to process the message successfully 
  * returns.
  */ 

static final int AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE = 1;
```

Consider to configure on that `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` this to `true`:

```
/**
 * Set the transaction mode that is used when creating a JMS {@link Session}.
 * Default is "false".
 * <p>Note that within a JTA transaction, the parameters passed to
 * {@code create(Queue/Topic)Session(boolean transacted, int acknowledgeMode)}
 * method are not taken into account. Depending on the Java EE transaction context,
 * the container makes its own decisions on these values. Analogously, these
 * parameters are not taken into account within a locally managed transaction
 * either, since the accessor operates on an existing JMS Session in this case.
 * <p>Setting this flag to "true" will use a short local JMS transaction
 * when running outside of a managed transaction, and a synchronized local
 * JMS transaction in case of a managed transaction (other than an XA
 * transaction) being present. This has the effect of a local JMS
 * transaction being managed alongside the main transaction (which might
 * be a native JDBC transaction), with the JMS transaction committing
 * right after the main transaction.
 * @see javax.jms.Connection#createSession(boolean, int)
 */
public void setSessionTransacted(boolean sessionTransacted) {
```

Comment: Added a simplified version of relevant config for AMQ.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW those beans are in their independent methods, Just clubbed it for the sake of simplicity.
setSessionTransacted doesn't seem to work. Whereas setting the sessionAcknowledgeMode to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE works. You can update your answer accordingly.

Comment: But with `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` you must ack message manually. It is indeed not acked when you get an exception, but at the same time it is not acked when you don't and you don't call that `javax.jms.Message#acknowledge()` yourself. Probably there is some option in ActiveMQ which makes your messages to be acked too early...